# Multi-field unique constraint where we include one or another field based on nullity

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, constraint

Suppose I have four columns

```
| x | y | z | w |
```

I would like the following constraint:

1. If `w` is `NULL`, then `x`, `y`, `z` must be unique.
2. If `w` is not `NULL`, then `x`, `y`, `w` must be unique.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

First, for constraint number 2, nothing special is needed. A `UNIQUE` constraint ignores - and accepts - `NULL` values so a simple unique constraint on `(w,x,y)` will work just fine enforcing that.

For constraint number 1, I don't think there's a way with DDL in version 5.6 so your best option is probably the trigger solution by @stefan.

If you can upgrade to 5.7, you can use a `GENERATED` column and a unique index on it:

```
ALTER TABLE t
  ADD wz int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE WHEN w IS NULL THEN z END),
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX x_y_z_uq (x, y, wz) ;
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something similar to this would be of help (use trigger(s) as @McNets has suggested):  create 2 triggers, one for each "unique" check required (article about emulating MySQL check constraints to be found [here](http://mysqlserverteam.com/new-and-old-ways-to-emulate-check-constraints-domain/)).  MySQL version used: 5.7

```
drop trigger xyzunique;

delimiter $
create trigger xyzunique before insert on uc
for each row
begin
  if new.w is null then
    if exists (
      select *
      from uc
      where x = new.x and y = new.y and z = new.z 
    )
    then
      signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'xyZ unique trigger: bad number';
    end if;
  end if;
end$
delimiter ;

drop trigger xywunique;

delimiter $
create trigger xywunique before insert on uc
for each row
begin
  if new.w is not null then
    if exists (
      select *
      from uc
      where x = new.x and y = new.y and w = new.w 
    )
    then
      signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'xyW unique trigger: bad number';
    end if;
  end if;
end$
delimiter ;
```

Table (for testing)

```
create table uc ( x integer, y integer , z integer , w integer ) ;
```

Insert tests: every second/subsequent insert must fail, when using identical values.

```
 -- insert test xyz unique: second insert must fail
mysql> insert into uc (x,y,z,w) values (1,11,111,null) ;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into uc (x,y,z,w) values (1,11,111,null) ;
ERROR 1644 (45000): xyZ unique trigger: bad number

-- insert test xzw unique: second insert must fail
mysql> insert into uc values (9,99,999,9999) ;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into uc values (9,99,999,9999) ;
ERROR 1644 (45000): xyW unique trigger: bad number
```

Check:

```
mysql> select * from uc;
+------+------+------+------+
| x    | y    | z    | w    |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |   11 |  111 | NULL |
|    9 |   99 |  999 | 9999 |
+------+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This will need more testing, of course.  Also, the 2 triggers could be merged into one etc.

Comment: Don't forget you probably want to account for updates as well as inserts.

Comment: @John M: very good point!